# Run Rake on other projects by Shell Script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell

I have a `publish.sh` file that does the job of copying files to other projects from a main project source.
I am not able to run rake command on the destination projects as well...

Is this possible?

Here's what I tried:

- Adding another `migrate.ssh` on the root of each project and calling it from the main project.
- Something like:

> rake -f $destination_folder$client"/Rakefile" tmp:clear assets:clean
>   log:clear RAILS_ENV=production

but it end up clearing always the main project.

Comment: you can call any shell script with `sh` method from within *rake*  script, like: `sh 'publish.sh'`. Or you do a call to rake with withing that shell script? Anyway why don't you write that scriptin ruby?

Comment: I call the rake within the `sh`. I consider the sh more powerful overall for all the tasks I need to do on the server, but anyway if you know how to rake other projects from a main project task it would be something to consider.

Comment: but how do you call the rake task just form a command line, to clean only a part of project. Attain it from the command line.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand the question. I want to run several rake commands in several projects, and to not do this on the command line directly I wanted to do this on the bash...does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, partually, because in order to put the commands into bash, you shell to simulate them manually, as if you are the bash script itself.

Comment: Sure, I simulated from he command line before...and had the same behaviour...

Comment: Do you mean the same, and incorrect?

Comment: Yes. The question is the same as running rake from another folder...

Comment: It seems the only way is to change current folder when you run the rake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I already had done this but seems not. The answer was clear and simple: Change directory first.

```
destination_folder="/Path/of_all_my_clients_app/"
client="client_name"

cd $destination_folder$client
rake tmp:clear assets:clean log:clear RAILS_ENV=production
...
```

Thanks majioa.